# Why is my UIScrollView not appearing?

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard, subclass

I'm trying to subclass a UIView that contains a UIScrollView inside of it. This is the code I'm using:

UIViewSubclass.h

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scroll;
```

UIViewSubclass.m

```
 @synthesize itemScrollView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    [self setUpScrollViewWithIdentifier:@"id"];
}
return self;
}

-(void)setUpScrollViewWithIdentifier:(NSString*)scrollViewID {

NSLog(@"Setting up Scroll View with the id of: %@",scrollViewID); //This is working

scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 90)];

//Subview of the scroll view
UIView *test = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
test.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[scroll addSubview:test];

[self addSubview:scroll]; // Adds the scrollview to the UIView
 NSLog(@"Subviews: %@",self.subviews);
}
```

ViewController.h

```
  #import "UIViewSubclass.h"

  IBOutlet UIViewSubclass *menuView;
```

View Controller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
menuView = [[UIViewSubclass alloc]init];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I also linked the view up in the storyboard and set the view's class to UIViewSubclass but for somereason the scroll view won't appear. But when i check this NSLog:

```
 NSLog(@"Subviews: %@",self.subviews);
```

It gives me this in the debugger:

```
Subviews: (
"<UIScrollView: 0x1d5a20e0; frame = (0 0; 320 90); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1d5a2420>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d5a1c60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>"
 )
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
scroll.contentSize = fooSize;
```

might be what you missing.